# How to install Selenium dependencies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to install Selenium on a PC that does not have access to the internet. I read a thread on Stack Overflow that I need to install Selenium dependencies first then install Selenium, but I don't think I did it correctly as I am very new to Python and Selenium.

Here is what I did:

1.- I downloaded selenium-selenium-4.5.0.tar.gz

2.- Archived this file in Selenium4.5.0 folder

3.- Go to that folder and ran the command python -m pip install * -f ./--no-index

At this point I got errors such as:

> Error: Invalid requirement: '*'
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate ....

What can I do next?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you are on Windows, I wonder if the `selenium-selenium-4.5.0.tar.gz` is the wrong bundle.

Comment: I am using Windows 10